# Add a folder before every single file request using mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a site on a local server and a remote server. While in development, the server has be in url.com/~user while on my localhost in development I am simply developing in root. ie if I include a file on the local server I simply refer to "/img/img.png" for example... while this is obviously going to return a 404 on the remote server as it would be looking for "/~user/img/img.png".

This is the same issue that was answered over @ [Problems with pointing to files on local server versus remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093986/problems-with-pointing-to-files-on-local-server-versus-remote) however what I am wondering here is if this can be solved with mod_rewrite? Defining SITE_ROOT works within the php files... but it doesn't fix the files being referred to in the CSS sheets.

Is it possible to simply tell my remote server to add /~user/ to every single file inclusion? ie a /img/img.png becomes /~user/img/img.png ?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess that you are on some kind of shared server in production.  The problem with your situation is that something like http://example.com/img/some.jpg will generate a request that (without special setup) will not hit .htaccess in the web directory in http://example.com/~user/.  So, unless you have access to the server-wide apache config, this won't work for you.

What you could do if you want to go this route is write the URLs as /~user/img/some.jpg.  You could do a rewrite on your development server, then, to get rid of the ~user.

Better yet, why include the leading slash at all?  That way, you get just img/some.jpg, which will be a relative path then.  If you are referencing the image in http://localhost/index.html, it will pull http://localhost/img/some.jpg.  If you are referencing the image in http://example.com/~user/index.html, it will pull http://example.com/~user/img/some.jpg.

Finally, what about just having a ~user directory on your development server so it's the same in both places?

Comment: I'm on a virtual server which I have server-wide config access.

Comment: I'm going to try getting my local server the same as the remote server.

Comment: Btw, with the relative image that would work, but I'm doing clean urls ie instead of events.php?id=32 its /events/32 and so the server is translating that as actual directories. with relative linking, it then tries to get something like /events/img/img.png which obviously doesn't exist! :|

Comment: In that case, mod_rewrite could help you with this also: RewriteRule ^(.+)/img/(.+)$ /img/$1 [L] might do the trick, provided the RewriteBase is set appropriately and the RewriteRule happens either in .htaccess in the main web directory or the corresponding directory in the main config.